# Siglent1104 oscilloscope channels lagging

Tags: oscilloscope

First I noticed that clock begins before chipselect gets pulled low on SPI. After eliminating potential sources I started to suspect the scope. I connected all 4 channels to function generator at different frequencies and observed 25ns gap between channel pairs. The probes were all the same 100Mhz stock probes that came with the scope set at x10, the 'deskew' was 0 on all channels. The 25ns was constant across different frequencies. On/off, auto calibration and factory reset did not fix the issue:

[image]

[image]

What could be the reason for this? Is the oscilloscope faulty?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It would appear that due to a recent hardware change, the two ADCs (one for channels 1 & 2, the other for 3 & 4) now have a skew that is not corrected for in the firmware.

Firmware version 6.1.37R9 is supposed to correct for this.

**Source:**
See 20th May 2022: [SDS1xx4X-E Firmware Revision History And Update Instructions](https://www.siglenteu.com//wp-content/uploads/dlm_uploads/2022/05/SDS1xx4X-E-Firmware-Revise-History-and-Update-Instructions.pdf)

*(This is assuming you have the newer hardware version '09-xx', of course).*